# How do I create a view in HTML only with Monaco Editor?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, ngx-monaco-editor

Currently I am building a Visual Studio Code Extension which will open a webview (html) as a preview. Currently it uses html as I've mentioned above to generate a view. I am currently looking to implement Monaco Editor inside of my extension code however I am unable to see the editor. I can only see the title:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>monaco editor</title>

        <!-- MONACO CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="_static/js/ext/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css">
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: rgb(140, 190, 190);">
        <h1>monaco editor</h1>
        <div id="monaco_editor" style="height:400px">
        </div>

        <!-- MONACO JS -->
        <script>var require = { paths: { 'vs': '_static/js/ext/monaco-editor/min/vs' } };</script>

        <script src="_static/js/ext/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="_static/js/ext/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
        <script src="_static/js/ext/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>

        <script>
        // CREATE AN EDITOR
        var h_div = document.getElementById('monaco_editor');
        var editor = monaco.editor.create(h_div, {
            value: [
                'function x() {',
                '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
                '}'
            ].join('\n'),
            language: 'javascript'
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this an issue with the paths not being present? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: see the Webview doc page to see how to transform the URLs for JavaScript to include

Comment: @rioV8 That answer is out of scope of my question.